# Long range (max. 4-5 km) Communication (using Arduino or PIC)

Tags: arduino, communication, pic, lora

I would like to communicate (send the sensors' measurement data) between a drone and Arduino/PIC within 4-5 km radius. I found LoRa modules (RFM95W and SX1276). However, I don't know for sure what would be the best option, because quick connection is crucial. What would be the most useful solution?

Comment: Hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: If you are looking for sending real-time data, LoRa is not the best solution. Besides, RFM95W and SX1276 are pretty much the same.

Comment: Thank you! Which modules are appropriate for real-time data sending? I have not found those yet.

Comment: It's always a trade off among band width, transmission range and power consuming. If you really need something real-time, a combination of LoRa and SIM could be one of the solutions, it's all depends on your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoRa is a great solution for data communication over long distances, but the sending time may be up to 1 second. Our company has been testing SX1276 at a distance of over 5 km and we were very satisfied. Solutions is the best, if you want to send data over long distances. You can also pack data. If you need sample code or a detailed description please contact me.

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer! 
How can I contact with you?

Comment: kozhevnikov@myriad-corp.com, kozhevnikov.peter@gmail.com